# ASP.NET Core 2.2 - Action Filter db Query Question

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I have users in our app, who are mapped to companies. When a user logs in and starts to make requests I want a way to validate if that user is currently mapped to the company for access to company resources.

The idea I had was to create a whole controller just to manage all of this, but someone mentioned ActionFilters as a much better and cleaner option, I have to agree after looking at it.

The idea is to have the controller setup as:

```
controller -  action - CompanyId - ReportId
```

So any request to root the system would just look up if there are any companies mapped to that logged in user.

But if the request included CompanyId then they'd go to that company's “portal” account page. It's really any request that includes CompanyId where I want the actionFilter to make a determination on if that user is allowed access.

1. Request comes in...
2. There is a CompanyId in the request!
3. ActionFilter:

Look up in db for all users assigned to that CompanyId.  Is current user within that list?  No? = kick'em out.

I tried to type in a code example, but the system told me to manually indent each line by 4 spaces, I was doing it from memory anyways so no idea how helpful it would have been anyways.

Comment: So what have you tried, where are you stuck? Are you asking how to access the database in an action filter?

Comment: That’s exactly it. Sorry for the newb question, but I’m trying to learn. Lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get your action parameters in your action filter and then get your database via `HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>()`.Refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53874045/how-do-i-get-configuration-cookie-and-dbcontext-in-action-filter-in-asp-net-cor).

```
public class TestActionFilter:Attribute,IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        //If companyId is action parameter
        var companyId= context.ActionArguments["companyId"].ToString();
        //If companyId1 is query string
        var companyId1= context.HttpContext.Request.Query["companyId1"].ToString();
        //If companyId2 is in request header
        var companyId2= context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["companyId2"].ToString();

        //get your dbcontext
        var db = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

        //EF core logic
        //...
    }
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

You could use it on action directly using `[TestActionFilter]` attribute or set as [global filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#filter-scopes-and-order-of-execution)

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new TestActionFilter()); // an instance
});
```

Comment: Ahhhh!  I see what you’re doing.  I saw that you have access to httpContext but couldn’t figure out how to pull access to the dB within it.